# How to install svn 1.8.5 with neon on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, svn, osx-mavericks, webdav, build

Does anyone of you installed svn 1.8.* together with neon on OS X Mavericks?

I followed this tutorial:

http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/

But after trying to configure svn to use neon:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-neon
```

I get this warning:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-neon
```

Building and installation work fine after this, but of course I can not connect to WEBDAV repositories.

Answer (score 5):

### to download the subversion-1.8.0 and subversion-1.8.9

http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/

Then unzip it.

### to setup compiler environment

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.9.xctoolchain
```

### to build serf (http client module) for svn

> As @Ben Reser mentioned:
>   Subversion no longer supports the neon http library with 1.8 and has
>   moved exclusively to using the serf http library.

```
cd ~/Downloads/subversion-1.8.0
sh get-deps.sh serf
cd serf/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

### note: if you failed on ./configure

messages you may see

> checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in
>   `~/Downloads/subversion-1.8.0/serf': configure: error: cannot run C
>   compiled programs. If you meant to cross compile, use`--host'. See
>   `config.log' for more details

It might be missing of the Xcode developer tools installed.

```
xcode-select --install
```

### to build svn 1.8.9

```
cd ~/Downloads/subversion-1.8.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-serf=/usr/local/serf
make
sudo make install
```

### to add svn path to your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
. ~/.bash_profile
```

### to verify

```
svn --version
```

==> you should see

```
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
```

### further more to update the svn client in Xcode

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
sudo -s
mkdir svn_old
mv svn* svn_old/
ln -s /usr/local/bin/svn* ./
./svn --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Subversion [no longer supports the neon http library with 1.8](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted) and has moved exclusively to using the serf http library.

Answer (score 1):

After extracting the ZIP archive I get this error invoking the shell script

```
MacBook-Pro:subversion-1.8.9 mario$ sh get-deps.sh serf
: command not found5: 
: command not found3: 
: command not found2: 
: invalid numbere 48: printf: 1
: command not found1: 
: command not found4: 
: command not found7: 
: command not found2: 
: command not found6: 
'et-deps.sh: line 68: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'et-deps.sh: line 68: `usage() {
```

After downloading the tar.gz archive and repeating the operation the shell script get-deps.sh ran successfully.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the carriage-return in the get-deps.sh file. I ran a script to remove these and clean the file and all ran fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/23649350/1463518 Script to delete carriage return

Comment: use http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx for headache free install

Answer (score 0):

You need to set here a path to neon as well like this: `--with-neon=/path_to_neon/neon-0.29.6`. 
It is not enough just to say `--with-neon`. :)

Comment: Yes, I also tried this before posting my problem: same warning. No WEBDAV access.